# Why does 2..toString() work?

Tags: javascript

Why does `2..toString()` return `2` but `2.toString()` throws this error?

Example:

```
console.log(2..toString()); // prints 2

// Firefox throws the error
// `SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal`
console.log(2.toString());

var x = 2;
console.log(x.toString()); // prints 2

// Firefox throws the error
//`TypeError: XML descendants internal method called on incompatible Number`
console.log(x..toString());
```

Comment: (2).toString() yields the expected result. ( not an answer but a test...)

Comment: Does IE too give error?

Comment: I know but why does `2..toString()` work too?

Comment: I suspect this is because `2` is a primitive value, and `(2)` or `2.` converts it to an object, but I don't really understand the mechanism there.

Comment: On 2.toString() Chrome throws "SyntaxError:Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`2` is just a number, it doesn't have any methods to call.

`2.` can be coerced into a string, which is an object (i.e. `'2.0'`), hence can have the method.

Just `2.toString()` will be parsed as `2.0tostring()`, which of course doesn't make sense.

Looking at how the two are parsed:

[image]

vs

[image]

The tool to generate these is here by the way: http://jsparse.meteor.com/

Comment: **Found it .the tool is here (http://jsparse.meteor.com/)**

Comment: can you please explain how the diagrams indicates that te first one is wrong ? both seems to be in a number box. I cant see how the diagrams helps.... can you please reply?

Comment: Sorry, had to get the kids breakfast halfway through – I agree, not sure the diagrams represent things correctly. It's a duplicate anyway, so perhaps ignore my answer.

Answer (score 8):

That's because `2.` is parsed as `2.0`, so `2..toString()` is equivalent to `2.0.toString()`, which is a valid expression.

On the other hand, `2.toString()` is parsed as `2.0toString()`, which is a syntax error.

Comment: `2.` yields `2` in Chromium's console.

Comment: @G.Kayaalp, yup, both `2 === 2.0` and `2. === 2.0` are `true`.

Comment: hate to be the devil's advocate here, but `2. === 2` is `true` as well

Comment: AFAIK JS does not have distinct types for integers and decimals. It has the `"number"` type, which is a 64 bit floating point number.

Comment: @G.Kayaalp, yes, you're right. That's way your console shows `2.0` as `2`, because the two expressions have both the same value and the same type. The same goes for `2.` versus `2`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi does `2` is also parsed as `2.0` ?

Comment: @Royi, nope, `2` without a trailing period is just parsed as `2`. However, add a trailing period and the parser will think it delimits the decimal part of the number, even if the programmer intended it to be the member resolution operator.

Answer (score 5):

```
2.toString()
```

The interpreter sees `2` and thinks, "oh, a number!" Then, it sees the dot and thinks, "oh, a decimal number!" And then, it goes to the next character and sees a `t`, and it gets confused. "`2.t` is not a valid decimal number," it says, as it throws a syntax error.

---

```
2..toString()
```

The interpreter sees `2` and thinks, "oh, a number!" Then, it sees the dot and thinks, "oh, a decimal number!" Then, it sees another dot and thinks, "oh, I guess that was the end of our number. Now, we're looking at the properties of this object (the number 2.0)." Then, it calls the `toString` method of the `2.0` object.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

As the Number object overrides the toString method of the Object object, you first have to explicity use paranthesis to indicate that it is a number, and not an object.

My guess is that `2.` implicitly defines it as a float, which is then able to use the `.toString()` method of the Number object, and not the method of the Object object.

Answer (score 1):

`2..toString()` will be interpreted as `2.0.toString()`.

Actually, `2.` is a number: `console.log(typeof 2.);` will be give: number